# How to add diagrams to a layer in a PyQGIS standalone application?

Tags: pyqgis, standalone

In my standalone application, I show different layers based on queries into a canvas.
Now I want to add a layer with charts over by the values of an attribute.
Is it possible in a standalone application?
I tried "QgsDiagramRenderer" but without Results.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code to generate a histogram diagram for two layer attributes "attribute_1" and "attribute_2":

```
def setHistogram(layer):
        # Set histogram and diagram settings:
        hist = QgsHistogramDiagram()
        ds = QgsDiagramSettings()
        dColors = {'attribute_1': QColor("cyan"),
                   'attribute_2': QColor("red")}
        ds.categoryColors = dColors.values()
        ds.categoryAttributes = dColors.keys()
        ds.font = QFont("Helvetica", 12)
        ds.transparency = 0
        ds.size = QSizeF(50.0, 50.0)
        ds.sizeType = 0
        ds.labelPlacementMethod = 1
        ds.scaleByArea = True
        ds.minimumSize = 0
        ds.BackgroundColor = QColor(255, 255, 255, 255)
        ds.PenColor = QColor("black")
        ds.penWidth = 0

        # Set renderer:
        renderer = QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer()
        renderer.setUpperValue(1000)  # Here you should set the maximum value of both attributes
        renderer.setUpperSize(QSizeF(20, 20))
        renderer.setLowerValue(0)
        renderer.setLowerSize(QSizeF(0, 0))
        renderer.setDiagram(hist)
        renderer.setDiagramSettings(ds)
        renderer.setClassificationAttribute(0)

        # Set diagram layer settings:
        layer.setDiagramRenderer(renderer)
        dls = QgsDiagramLayerSettings()
        dls.dist = 0
        dls.priority = 0
        dls.xPosColumn = -1
        dls.yPosColumn = -1
        dls.placement = 0

        layer.setDiagramLayerSettings(dls)
        layer.triggerRepaint()
```